# How to create a Google Fusion Table in Google Drive's hidden app folder

Tags: google-drive-api, dart, google-fusion-tables

I'm trying to use Google's Fusion Table service as a backend database for an app I'm building.  It almost works perfectly, but I need to create or move the table file into Google Drive's hidden app folder.   Many things could go wrong if the user edit's or deletes the file manually.

It's doesn't seem that the Fusion Table api supports selecting a parent folder... it creates the table file in the root every time.

---

I've tried the following methods (code in Dart) ...

**1) Updating table file's parent reference with Drive api**

```
File folder = await getAppFolder();
var folderRef = new ParentReference()
  ..id = folder.id;
file.parents.add(folderRef);
await drive.files.update(file, file.id);
```

> (status: 403, message: Method not supported for appdata contents)

Note that this works with plain folders, but not the app folder.

**2) Create new table file using Drive api**

```
File appFolder = await getAppFolder();
var parent = new ParentReference()
  ..id = appFolder.id;
var file = new File()
  ..title = 'MyDatabase'
  ..mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.fusiontable'
  ..parents = [parent];
await drive.files.insert(file);
```

> (status: 400, message: Bad Request)

Whatever settings I change, this does not seem to work.

**3) Copy table file into app folder using Drive api**

```
File origFile = await getFile(title);
File folder = await getAppFolder();
var folderRef = new ParentReference()
  ..id = folder.id;
var newFile = new File()
  ..title = title
  ..parents = [folderRef];
newFile = await drive.files.copy(newFile, origFile.id);
await drive.files.insert(newFile);
```

> (status: 403, message: Only folders or files with content stored in Drive are allowed within the appdata folder)

Comment: one final thing you could try would be to create a folder in appdata and then use that folder id as the parent of your table. However I suspect the last error message "(status: 403, message: Only folders or files with content stored in Drive are allowed within the appdata folder)" is the show stopper. I can't think of a reason why appdata should impose that restriction, but it seems it does. Since a fusion table is not "stored content", you're hosed.

Comment: Yes, it appears you're correct.   I get the same error when trying to use a folder inside of appdata.    It also seems that trying to add a doc/sheet gives the same error.   That's a shame... you would think that technically it would be as simple as hiding it from the user.